# How do I get back from a fragment to a previous fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When working with java in Android Studio, how do I get back from a fragment to a previous fragment?

1. To use the bottom tab, I am using fragments divided into three in MainActivity. I opened another fragment on that fragment to input information, but when I press Back on the phone, the application quits. How should I do it?

This is the code I added to MainActivity.

```
**public void onBackPressed() {
        List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        for(Fragment fragment : fragmentList){
            if(fragment instanceof onBackPressedListener){
                ((onBackPressedListener)fragment).onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeBackPressed < 1500){
            finish();
            return;
        }
        lastTimeBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Press the 'Back' button again to finish.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }**
```

2. And can the page that receives information from being entered in a different way than a fragment?
3. Is it possible to delete the fragment while storing the input information after it is input from the fragment? When I go back, the stack is still piled up, so I keep seeing the previously entered information.

Comment: https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62 Here  is a medium article that might help you gain a deeper understanding

Answer (score 1):

For the fragment you add that allows the user to input information, make sure to call:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

during the fragment transaction where you add the fragment.

Then get rid of the `onBackPressed` override, it's not necessary.

`addToBackStack()` will enable automatic handling of the BACK button press, removing the fragment transaction.